# How to concatenate strings within df.to_csv file directory

Tags: python, pandas

Good day,

I'm currently working on the python script that creates a txt with file name `C4-4TH-6TH.txt`.

I want the file name to be user input `(FileName = C4-4TH-6TH)`. However, I was having trouble concatenating the complete absolute file path using the + sign.

Is the a simpler way to concatenate strings with a file path?

Below is my code

```
File_Name = "C4-4TH-6TH.txt"
df.to_csv('r'+'D:\20210719-Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD\'+File_Name',index=None,sep=\t')
```

and this is the error i'm getting

> File "", line 120 df.to_csv('r'+'D:\20210719-PDP Architects Zenya Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD'+File_Name',index=None,sep=\t') ^ SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: Can you add to your question what problems you had? Add the code you have used for the user input and the concatenating as well as the error you are getting

Comment: do you want `df.to_csv(rf'D:\20210719-Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD\{FileName}.txt',index=None,sep='\t')`?

Comment: Here is my code:  File_Name = "C4-4TH-6TH.txt"  and df.to_csv('r'+'D:\20210719-Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD\'+File_Name',index=None,sep=\t') and this is the error i'm getting File "<ipython-input-6-cecca3e72ccd>", line 120
    df.to_csv('r'+'D:\20210719-PDP Architects Zenya Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD\'+File_Name',index=None,sep=\t')
                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: please add your code to the question and format it accordingly

Comment: You are making 2 mistakes: (1) `... +File_Name'` should be `... +File_Name` (last `'` removed), which leads to the error message, (2) `'r'+...`  hasn't the effect you think it has: the `r` is a _meta_ character, it needs to be outside of the strings, not inside `'`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "../" #you can change any with / symbol.
name= "abc"
```

you can create a string as

```
s = path+name+'.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `os.path` package provides useful path manipulation. In your case I think this should work:

```
from os import path
filename = input("Enter filename:")
base_path = 'D:\20210719-Loft\B-Structural\ELEMENT DESIGN\Column\CHB-FCD\'
complete_path = path.join(base_path, filename)
df.to_csv(complete_path, index=None, sep=\t')
```